# How to fetch User from Entity Reference in Rules? (to obtain email from a user field)

Tags: entities, rules, emails

I'm using an **Entity Reference field** with select list, *target type **User***

(so a user can be selected and saved as event organizer)

**How can I fetch the actual email (instead of name) so i can use it in send mail as recipient?**

I tried using [event-node:field-eventorganizer:uid] as the token but doesn't work.
Also tried to add a **Fetch by entity** User in hope that could make the mail token available from that user field.

FYI-I checked the nodes fields and the user ID is definitely in the field

```
field_eventorganizer (Array, 1 element)
und (Array, 1 element)
0 (Array, 1 element)
target_id (String, 2 characters ) 43
```

I read tons of posts and tried many options but just couldn't figure it out, please help.

Comment: you have target id it's your uid so load the user like `$user = user_load(field_eventorganizer['und'][0]['target_id']);`  and then you can get the mail field `$mail = $user->mail->value`

Comment: add a condition, entity has field, your ER field, then another contition, entity has field, with your ER field, user email field, done. it could be more accurate my comment or ansewr if you explain better your event and whats fields yoy have.

Comment: @berramou thanks but i'm using rules for sendmail and need to be able within sendmail to use the mail field from the user field, thus can't use code.

Comment: @pinueve oh wow you're the best, thanks for the quick and relevant answer, it would never occur to me that the relationship linkage has to be done as "condition" instead of an Action :) I only added the first condition which already worked via "registration:entity:field-eventorganizer:0:mail". Hence wondering if the second condition is needed at all?
Actually I'm wondering how I can do it so accepts multiple users, as  sendmail doesn't accept "registration:entity:field-eventorganizer:mail"

FYI - I'm only using one ER User field (no email fields)

Comment: Rules is a beauty, to do that you need lists and loops,  you need to leran more, for D7 (many concepts apply to D8) see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QL1Rp69Lq80&list=PL84B6FFA4F7ACAD57 & https://drupalize.me/series/learning-rules-framework-series, good luck

Comment: thanks, hopefully i'll manage. If i understood correct a loop could go through all "[registration:entity:field_eventorganizer:" objects (if that's the right word) instead of inserting [registration:entity:field_eventorganizer:0:mail] , [registration:entity:field_eventorganizer:1:mail],[registration:entity:field_eventorganizer:2:mail] etc. ??

Cheers and have a nice evening, you're the man!

Comment: @pinueve I'm very close but missing something. I added a "List of user items" variable list_all_eventorganizers_emails (expecting to store all user objects including mail field) before creating the loop. In the loop I 'Add an item to a list' from the Loop's (variable) List item: single-mail-list-item Appended to list-all-eventorganizers-emails BUT in the SendMail after the loop(outside) for the recipients I still get list-all-eventorganizers-emails:0:mail instead of list-all-eventorganizers-emails:mail (for all emails to be used of all collected users). Any clues/help please?

Comment: To clarify
1) VARIABLE to collect all users (to retrieve emails in the sendmail after the loop) do I need to add a variable BEFORE the loop or use the Loops own list item? As it states "used for holding each list item in the loop"
2) Use FETCH by entity id or by property in the loop to obtain individual USER stored in field_eventorganizer (containing multiple users)?
3) In the loop: Add an item to a list, storing into the variable created before the loop or that of the loop itself?
4) Tried both but it just wont accept the variable name/data selector as it requires to drill down further

Comment: @pinueve I solved it, finally :-) I had to insert the mail items via 'data set' action from within the loop, into a TEXT variable outside of it while appending the values with formatting for email comma  separated "<email@test.com>,". Maybe there is another way to store them in a list variable and retrieve them via data selector but couldn't figure this out unfortunately.

Comment: add second condition i suggested in order to avoid '[registration:entity:field_eventorganizer:0:mail]', with second condition you will have a nice list avilable.

Comment: Oops sorry I missed the second condition, thanks for pointing out, will definitely try this. Have a nice weekend, I learned lots

Comment: @pinueve i tried adding the second condition but the data selector won't give me the user email" field, instead it too only goes to "registration:entity:field-eventorganizer:0". For the second condition I expected to select "registration:entity:field-eventorganizer" and as value "mail" field as per your instructions, any thoughts what I might have missed? Maybe it helps if I provide some more info. Thanks for hanging in with me there :)

Comment: "registration:entity:field-eventorganizer:0" last zero means its a list, make another loop